# How to prevent parent object from activating child object's event

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the code. You are supposed to get from the left square to the right one without exiting the blue div or entering the red one. The problem is that both the red div and its child, the right square have the same event listener, but one ends the game in a loss and the other one in a victory. Is there a way to fix this without redoing everything?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

<style>
html {
    text-align: center;
}

.outer {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 36%;
    right: 50%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    background-color: lightskyblue;
}

.mid {
    width: 440px;
    height: 440px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background-color: #ffbcbc;
}

.inner {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 170px;
    background-color: rgb(134, 255, 134);
}

#in1 {
    float: left;
    border-left: none;
}

#in2 {
    float: right;
    border-right: none;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="outer" id="outer">

        <div class="mid" id="mid">

            <div class="inner" id="in1">
            </div>

            <div class="inner" id="in2">
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <script>
    let out = document.getElementById("outer")
let mid = document.getElementById("mid")
let in1 = document.getElementById("in1")
let in2 = document.getElementById("in2")

in1.addEventListener("mouseover", GameStart)

function GameOver() {
    alert("Pokušajte ponovno")
    out.removeEventListener("mouseleave", GameOver)
    mid.removeEventListener("mouseenter", GameOver)
    in2.removeEventListener("mouseenter", GameWon)
    return
}

function GameWon() {
    alert("Pobijedili ste")
    out.removeEventListener("mouseleave", GameOver)
    mid.removeEventListener("mouseenter", GameOver)
    in2.removeEventListener("mouseenter", GameWon)
    return
}

function GameStart() {
    in1.addEventListener("mouseleave", Game)
}

function Game() {
    in1.removeEventListener("mouseleave", Game)
    out.addEventListener("mouseleave", GameOver)
    mid.addEventListener("mouseover", GameOver)
    in2.addEventListener("mouseenter", GameWon)
}

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have provided you the correct way to do that.  By the way in your question you have given example of red and blue boxes while they are no where to be found in the code. That's why I came up with the general solution  :) Enjoy and do accept the answer if it helps :)

Comment: The code you provided does not correspond to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `event capture` in this case. And explicitly look for the `e.target` (the element which was clicked) from which the event was fired and handle that logic seperately.

In the demo example, I have mimicked your game example : Try this

```js
document.querySelector(".parent").addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
   if(e.target.className === "child1"){
      console.log("Continue the game")
   }
   if(e.target.className === "child2"){
      console.log("Game Over !!!")
   }

})
```

```css
.child1,.child2{
  background:teal;
  height:100px;
  width:300px;
}

.child1{
margin-bottom:2rem;
}
```

```html
 <div class="parent">

        <div class="child1">
        </div>

        <div class="child2">
        </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: I have provided the Demo Code to Demonstrate :)

Comment: @B.Raut : Yup bro :)